# Best practice for updating dynamic api values in html tags

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am fetching api information every minute updating a dashboard.

An example of the payload is

```
      "dew_point": "46.6", 
      "humidity": "44.0", 
      "is_cloudy": "Cloudy", 
      "is_raining": "No", 
      "is_wet": "No", 
      "temperature": "69.4", 
      "timestamp": "2020-08-28 22:53:44", 
      "wind_speed": "2.2"
```

I have a div full of p's that populate with that data and the API payload is saved in a variable called data.

Currently, I am updating this data by doing

```
// Api data saved in data
var data = response;
var temperatureText = document.getElementById("temperatureText");
temperatureText.textContent = data.temperature;
```

However, in my application, the api is returning about 50 data entries. I feel like I am hardcoding this update process, and using some formatting on tag id's and the api names could make this easier in some loop.

What is the correct process on updating this data? Should I change the ids of my text paragraphs to match the API payload and loop through? Should I build the div with the API response on the first loading of the page, call each paragraph the name of the API data then loop through updating in future api calls?

I want to make this as modular as possible.

Comment: I usually tend to use `data-` attributes. You can easily select them using `[data-x]` and then use the value to identify the respective field from your API response.

Comment: @Sirko looking at charliefl example #2, that is the technique you would use developing?

Comment: Yes, although I think the additional class is not really necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible approaches here:

1- Keep an array of the property names within the data you want displayed and do as you suggested, make ID's in elements have formats that are consistent with payload properties.

Then loop over the array of properties  you want displayed and insert in DOM

Simple example:

```js
const data={dew_point:"46.6",humidity:"44.0",is_cloudy:"Cloudy",is_raining:"No",is_wet:"No",temperature:"69.4",timestamp:"2020-08-28 22:53:44",wind_speed:"2.2"};

const wanted_keys = ["dew_point", "temperature"];

wanted_keys.forEach(k => document.getElementById('w-' + k).textContent = data[k])
```

```html
Dew: <span id="w-dew_point"></span>, Temp:<span id="w-temperature"></span>
```

OR

2- Do the reverse and store the associated property names in `data-` attributes on the elements that all have common class and loop over the collection inserting text found by the properrty in the data attribute

```js
const data={dew_point:"46.6",humidity:"44.0",is_cloudy:"Cloudy",is_raining:"No",is_wet:"No",temperature:"69.4",timestamp:"2020-08-28 22:53:44",wind_speed:"2.2"};

document.querySelectorAll('.w-data').forEach(el=> el.textContent = data[el.dataset.key])
```

```html
Dew: <span class="w-data" data-key="dew_point"></span>, Temp:<span class="w-data" data-key="temperature"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am leaning towards option #2. Would you recommend me building the html with javascript (since its about 50 items) and having a const weatherKey which contains all the names from the API and attach it to each element?

Comment: You could. I didn't go that way simply because I don't know the layout used. If it was table for example would be simple to keep inserting rows